# Ejecutar acción desde TextView presionando enter sin usar clicklistener y mantener foco en TextView

Tags: mysql, android, studio, server, código-de-barras

Quisiera quitar el botón de consultar, y que al dar enter en el TextView se ejecute la consulta sin la necesidad del botón, 
y que el foco se quede en el editText para poder seguir poniendo códigos de barras y solo presionar enter para que se consulte

Actualmente se ejecuta la consulta con set on click listener, pero tengo que estar dando click al botón y el foco se queda en el botón, por lo que tengo que dar click al TextView otra vez para insertar otro código, y quisiera que se ejecutara con un escaner de codigos de barras, por eso quisiera que el cursor siempre se quede en el TextView y que se ejecute la consulta con la tecla enter después de poner el codigo de barras

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText prod;
    TextView res;
    Button bsq;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        prod=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtcb);
        res=(TextView)  findViewById(R.id.edtxtnombre);
        bsq=(Button)    findViewById(R.id.btnconsulta);

     bsq.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
         consulta();

         }
     });


    }

    public Connection conexionBD(){
        Connection  cnn=null;
        try {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy politica= new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(politica);
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            cnn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.0.33;databaseName=09Data;user=consulta;password=zz586;");

        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return  cnn;

    }


    public void consulta(){
        try {
            Statement stm = conexionBD().createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ItemSellingPrices WHERE PriceLineID =1 AND ItemID ='" + prod.getText().toString() + "'");

            if(rs.next()){
                res.setText(rs.getString(7));

            }
            prod.setText("");

        }catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="107dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="107dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="CODIGO DE BARRAS" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtcb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="82dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="82dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:hint="codigo de barras"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="false" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnconsulta"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="127dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="127dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="109dp"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="CONSULTAR" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtxtnombre"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnconsulta"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="81dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="81dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="285dp"
        android:layout_height="87dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="57dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="57dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="37dp"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/logo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que lo que quieres es sustituir tu botón de búsqueda por un evento te teclado.

Para recibir un evento de teclado en la vista debes de tener;

```
edittext.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
edittext.requestFocus();
```

Y seguir como en el código de ejemplo

```
final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // si presiona enter
        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
            (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
          // modifica por tu método
          Toast.makeText(HelloFormStuff.this, edittext.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

referencia: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233586/android-execute-function-after-pressing-enter-for-edittext